# How send data one page to another page after clicking submit button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

i Have a one problem want to share with all of you.
I am develop a custom page in WordPress here is the link of the page http://muhammadimran.info/testing/ when i try to click on new document button and try to submit form it give me error. Here is my code for this please tell me how i can give link in WordPress in action

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="home1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name1">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Startdate">Start Date</label>
                    <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" class="datepicker" type="text" name="start" required="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Enddate">End Date</label>
                    <input id="datepicker1" class="form-control"  class="datepicker" type="text" name="end" required="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Users">Users</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="users" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Fileupload">File Upload</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" class="file" name="file" required="">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitbutton" name="submit">

            </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you develop plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the beloe steps:

1. create a Template:
   Home1 Template  with file name home1.php
2. create a page and select the recently create template (Home1 Template).
3. replace the form action

   ```
   <form action="home1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
   ```

   with

   ```
   <form action="http://siteur/templateur/" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
   ```
4. in home1.php

   `print_r($_POST);`